# how to integrate kafka with rest and to pyspark?

Tags: python, flask, apache-kafka

i have a rest service written in flask sitting at localhost:5000. It has endpoint function 'parser'.
It parses one website.

```
from flask import Flask
import requests
from flask import jsonify
from flask import make_response
from flask import request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods = ['GET'])
def main():
    return jsonify('service is waiting, standby..')

@app.route("/parser/<string:website>", methods = ['GET'])
def parse(website):  
    if website != 'news.com':
        return make_response(jsonify({'error': 'only news.com is parsable' }), 404)
    else:
        result = main_parse()#need to send variable result via kafka to streaming for analysis
        return make_response(jsonify("parsing this website...", 200))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True)
```

The function main_parse has other stuff in it, but it returns some parsed data -a list of lists.

I never used kafka before, how do I throw this parsed data result **via kafka** or kafka topic(task?) to pyspark for basic analysis? I m naive.

It should be a pipeline without clicking buttons- once rest api receives correct website name - it does the rest.

Comment: What do you want to know exactly? How you read from kafka with pyspark or how you write this data from flask to kafka?

Comment: @cronoik, how to write this dataset from flask to kafka. do we actually send entire data to kafka?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need Spark for Kafka in this code, and I would not put Spark in any web server as it is meant for distributed processing (meaning your Spark code wouldn't even be running within the context of Flask, if you did have a Spark cluster).

You can use any Kafka Python library, which can be easily found on Github for examples and usage documentation.

> do we actually send entire data to kafka

Sure. Keep in mind; Kafka has a default record limit of 1MB

Comment: thx, but spark is not on any webserver, i just use it to process and write to a db

Comment: But you cannot do that all from Flask

Comment: Also, you should really look at using Kafka Connect rather than Spark for that